# Path for opening PyCharm using git bash?

Tags: python, git, github, pycharm, gitversion

I have tried the following lines in GitHub bash. I need to set path for PyCharm in Git Bash so that PyCharm should open from the bash.

```
$ git config core.editor "PyCharm"
fatal: not in a git directory

$ git config core.editor "PyCharm --wait"
fatal: not in a git directory
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To use PyCharm as the default editor in Bash (on Windows), you need to find where the PyCharm .exe is saved and copy the path to this .exe into the following command in Bash:

```
git config --global core.editor "'<path to PyCharm.exe>' --wait"
```

Comment: HUGE THANKS my friend! I've been trying to do this for so long! I was missing the `--wait` and also, much more insidious, the `''`. Thank you so much, I was so tired of the last editor (that I shall not name)!

Answer (score 0):

The command that you are running is trying to set the editor for a specific repository, and because you are not in one it tells you accordingly. To set the editor globally, include the `--global` flag in your command like `git config --global core.editor "PyCharm"`

Comment: I have tried it but still pycharm is not opening

Comment: @Honey When are you trying to get it to open? What command specifically are you running to open PyCharm with?

Comment: using code in the same lines vs code editor has opened with the same project name i dont undrestand why pycharm is not opening

Comment: @Honey the core.editor sets your editor for commit and tag massages, not for just editing files in general. When you commit something, why do you want pycharm to be the text editor? I think you might be misunderstanding what core.editor sets exactly.

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

1. start with `git init` wherever your project is.
2. this should create .git folder from git.
3. now run your commands.

the idea is to run these commands where ever .git is present ( that in your repostiroy which is created since once you run git init)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, write this command in Bash:

```
git config --global core.editor "pycharm-community"
```