# How to invoke Pycharm from Git Bash

Tags: python, bash, git, pycharm

I am trying to set Pycharm as the default code editor for git bash.

Just like notepad can be invoke form git bash with `start notepad program.py`.

I tried setting Pycharm as the default code editor, and some other things.

`git config --global core.editor "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.1\bin\pycharm64.exe"`
`git config --global core.editor "charm . --wait"`
`git config --global core.editor pycharm`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69832954/7976758 `git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.1\bin\pycharm64.exe' --wait"` (note quotes). Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bpycharm%5D+core.editor

Comment: still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke PyCharm by including its path in '.bashrc' or '.bashrc-profile'

Follow this steps to get this done:

1. Open .bashrc via your text editor

   nano ~/.bashrc
2. Add the path to .bashrc by replacing  with actual path of pycharm in your system

   export PATH=$PATH:

example:

```
export PATH=$PATH:'/c/Program\ Files/JetBrains/PyCharm\ Community\ Edition\ 2021.1/bin'
```

3. Apply changes and hit following command

   source ~/.bashrc

Thank you!

Comment: Done this. Still not working.

Comment: Please explain “not working”.  How are you attempting to invoke PyCharm?  Also, ensure the path you’ve added to PATH, matches that where PC actually lives; as the path mentioned above does not appear to match your installation, per the question.

Comment: In the example: `Edition\ 2021.1/bin`. This should be `Edition\ 2021.1.1/bin`.

Comment: I think it a Pycharm thing. Github doesnt even specify for Pycharm in its docs.
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/associating-text-editors-with-git?platform=windows